# putting a space between entries in a ListBox

Tags: c#

How to you put a space between entries of a listbox?

listBox will be contacts

```
Tom
987 sugar st.
Frank
123 maple dr.
Jessica
456 bedford st.
```

I want to put a space between those contacts. I got this code so far:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("/n");
    }
```

But the `Console.WriteLine("/n");` does not put a space between the next entry

Comment: It should be `\n`. Also `Console.WriteLine` has nothing to do with listBoxes, except if you're going to output the listBox item values into the console, which you're not doing here.

Comment: Add a blank item in between?...

Comment: Honestly this question looks like something that needs a book, not an answer -- you have to understand what `Console.WriteLine` does and why it is not applicable here, not just remove it and use something else.

Comment: according to the C# book I got Console.WriteLine() is used in Windows Form Applications. I just can't get a space between entries of the listbox

Comment: @user2514327 What book? Name and shame.

Comment: C# programming:From Problem Analysis to Program Design

Comment: What do you want the \n for? when you add an item in a listbox it goes to the next line anyway. Console.WriteLine by the way is for Console application and not for WinForms which i suspect the one that you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with @AndreyShchekin's comment, here is a solution.

You're not working with the `Console`.. you're working with a `ListBox`. To that end.. you need to do something with the `ListBox` to have a space between items.

Perhaps one way is to add a blank item? Like so:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need there. 
try adding an empty element in the listbox. `listBox1.Items.Add(string.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a empty line like:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add("");
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
}
```

Or use `Environment.NewLine` like

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
}
```